# SSIS This Year verses Last Year extract best design

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a requirement to write a report using SSIS to extract data from a SQL database into a CSV file.

The data is the sales for this week along side the sales for the same week last year.

I've written an SSIS package with two data flow tasks, one which loads the data into a persisted table and one which extracts it into the CSV.

The problem is the performance is really poor. For this week we are looking at around 1000 sales records but the corresponding week last year has 1.5 million records +

The same table holds this week and last year, so it's almost the same query but with different date parameters.

So far I've tried:

1. One query with two CTE's joined. Performance was 45 minutes
2. An insert into the table just for this years data and a separate update to add last years figures. Operation took 20 minutes.
3. Two SQL Sources, which have the NOLOCK hint, which are then sorted and joined with the Merge Join. I had hoped both would run in parallel but I stopped it after 45 minutes.

Even with option 2 at 20 minutes it will be roughly 4x slower than any other SSIS package in the estate.

My question is what is the best design practice for getting data out the same table twice please?

Comment: If you just run `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable AS T WHERE T.sale_date >= '2020-04-28' AND T.sale_date < '2020-05-05' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable AS T WHERE T.sale_date >= '2019-04-28' AND T.sale_date < '2019-05-05'` in management studio, how long does it take to execute and how many rows are returned?  What does the shape of the data look like (# of columns and their data types)?

Comment: I hadn't considered a Union All but will try it when I get back to work on Monday. Thanks

Comment: The general rule for efficient ETL is always reduce the quantity of data you're moving (width of data & the depth/number of rows). Benchmark what the cost to get your extract and then compare that time to the process of moving and storing it elsewhere and measure whether the difference is material to the business needs.

Comment: The other observation I'd make is to identify how far back the report data source needs to go. Perhaps you only need a rolling year, whatever. Load data for the historical periods for all time and then your ETL is only concerned with what's new (and if you have to deal with changed) but that reduces your daily/weekly universe of change to 3 months (arbitrary duration) of data changes to ETL - your business should be able to provide more insight into their processes.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the Union All idea but it didn't work. I needed This Year and Last Year in the same row and couldn't see how to get it to work.

I've got it down to less than 10 minutes by removing some of the columns and performing a lookup in SSIS on them instead and this has improved performance to an acceptable level.

Thank you for your support.